# Add a custom exception to the "Methods should not have too many parameters" SonarQube rule

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

In sonar rules, there is a [S00107](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-107) rule for "*Methods should not have too many parameters*". This rule has exceptions for some annotations:

> **Exceptions**
>
> Methods annotated with Spring's @RequestMapping (and
>   related shortcut annotations, like @GetRequest) or @JsonCreator may
>   have a lot of parameters, encapsulation being possible. Such methods
>   are therefore ignored.

Is it possible to add another annotations to this exceptions?

**My case:** I have constructors, annotated by the Lombok's `@Builder`, which contains a lot of parameters! So i want to ignore this rule on these constructors.

```
public class MyClass extends MySupperClass {
  @Builder
  public MyClass(String a, int b, ..., String z) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `@Builder` to class instead?

Comment: @user7294900 No currently i can't. The constructor consists fields of the current class and its super-classes.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add @SuppressWarnings("squid:S00107")

Comment: you should add it to your class or method

Comment: I don't want to change the code. I prefer change or customize sonar rule(s) in SonarQube.

Comment: I can help only this way sorry. It's not a big change

Answer (score 1):

Move `@Builder` to class level,

If you need super fields use lombok's [@SuperBuilder](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) in class level

> The @SuperBuilder annotation produces complex builder APIs for your classes. In contrast to @Builder, **@SuperBuilder also works with fields from superclasses**

Intellij IDEA's lombok-plugin [version 0.27](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/) added support

> Fixed #513: Add support for @SuperBuilder

Comment: No i can't use @SuperBuilder! The lombok-plugin in Intellij IDEA does not support it. and also its experimental.

Comment: @Arya plugin version 0.27 add support https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/

Comment: @Arya Without code change, notice sonar rules aren't flexible as one would expect, so either `SuppressWarnings` on method as suggested by Nick